# Use get_the_excerpt is returning nothing outside of loop

Tags: excerpt

I am trying to get the excerpt of a blog post using the get_the_excerpt and it just returns blank every time and i cant work out what i am doing wrong. Here it was i got:

Template:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                    <?php $blogPost1 = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
                                                                'numberposts' => 1,
                                                                'category'    => 42,
                                                                'orderby'     => 'post_date',
                                                                'order'       => 'DESC'
                                                            ) ); ?>

                    <h1><?php echo $blogPost1[0]['post_title']; ?></h1>
                    <br>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt( $blogPost1[0]['ID'] ); ?>
                    <br>
                </div>
```

My Content:

```
https://youtu.be/BF2Ksrxu_QY
<div></div>
<div>Ok, so I’m supposed to be writing a review for this month’s film review- but I’m genuinely struggling to keep a straight face, let alone to not just crack up laughing. ‘Why?’, you may ask; well, the reason is: this month’s film is <i>The Snowman</i>, and I don’t think I’ve laughed so hard at something so unintentionally funny, in such a long time. Yes, I know what you’re thinking- but isn’t <i>The Snowman</i> that new crime thriller film with what’s-his-name-<i>Fassbender</i> in it? And the answer is yes, it is- but I think the filmmakers have missed a trick here, it really should’ve just been made as an intentional comedy!</div>
<div></div>
<!--more-->
<div>It is safe to say that when I heard Swedish Director, <i>Tomas Alfredson</i> (who has made such greats as: <i>Tinker Tailor Soldier Spy</i> and <i>Let The Right One In</i>), was going to be taking the helm of this project, I was excited to watch the finished product (despite the fact that <i>Martin Scorsese</i> had been the original Director on board); however the Crime novel, penned by Norwegian writer, <i>Jo Nesbø</i> (which also happens to be the 7th book in the ‘Detective Harry Hole’ series), was not in safe hands- as it turns out.</div>
```

I am not sure what im doing wrong or what I should be doing instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the post does not have a manual excerpt (as in one added to the Excerpt box on the post edit screen) then `get_the_excerpt()` used `wp_trim_excerpt()` to generate an excerpt. The problem is that `wp_trim_excerpt()` uses the content of the global `$post` object, which is set in the loop, regardless of any ID passed to `get_the_excerpt()`.

So to use `get_the_excerpt()` outside the loop you need to use `setup_postdata()` to set the global `$post` to the desired post:

```
<?php 
$blogPost1 = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'category'    => 42,
    'orderby'     => 'post_date',
    'order'       => 'DESC'
) ); 

global $post;

$post = $blogPost1[0]; // Post must be assigned to the global $post variable.

setup_postdata( $post );
?>

<!--  Now you can use template tags without specifying the ID. -->
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<br>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<br>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

*But*, based on the content you've provided, you're using the `<!--more-->` tag, so you don't actually want the excerpt. To show only content above the more tag you need to use `the_content()`. `the_content()` works so that the content above the more tag is displayed only on non-singular pages, while the full text is displayed on single pages. Note that this behaviour is regardless of whether `the_content()` is in the main query or not. To force it to only show the content above the more tag you need to use the global `$more` variable:

```
setup_postdata( $post );

global $more;

$original_more = $more;
$more = 0;
?>

<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<br>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<br>

<?php 
wp_reset_postdata(); 

$more = $original_more;
```

Comment: Thanks ive currently got this on a custom page and im trying both of your ways and it doesnt seem to be doing anything it just seems to be empty

Comment: Is the title appearing?

Comment: I  am getting the title of the page and not the post when using the second option.